# python subprocess file does not exist

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, execute, os.system

I swear I changed nothing, and this was working a week ago.  Yet now every time I call a path with os.system or subprocess.call, I am getting the error "Error: file NBK.swn does not exist".

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call('"H:/2012/yada yada yada/swanrun" NBK')
```

To get this to run normally, I open the command prompt in H:/2012/yada yada yada/ and type "swanrun NBK", which works fine.  If I run the same code, but remove the 'NBK' at the end, which is the file swanrun is supposed to run, swanrun successfully runs, but of course doesn't know which file to run.  Please help!

Comment: In what directory does `NBK_local.swn` exist?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, the error is "Error: file NBK.swn does not exist".  NBK.swn exists in H:/2012/yada yada yada/

Answer (score 1):

Either use the full path to `"NBK"`, or set the current working directory:

```
import subprocess 

path = "H:/2012/yada yada yada/"
subprocess.call('"H:/2012/yada yada yada/swanrun" NBK', cwd=path)
```

Edit:
Normally if a file argument isn't a fully qualified path an application will look in its pre-defined data directories (if any), the executable's directory, the current working directory, or some directory relative to the current working directory or executable's directory. The `cwd` option sets the working directory, which you should set to the directory from which you can run "`swanrun NBK`" successfully as described in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the problem (same result).  However, you are on to something, as I was able to determine that the problem was that it wasn't looking in the correct location for the input file (NBK.swn).  I ended up using a workaround, using shutil to copy the input file to the working directory and then copy the output from the working directory back to the input file directory.  Not elegant but it works.  If anyone has the proper solution, I'm still all ears!  Thanks!

Comment: I just provided an example path. Change the working directory to the path of NBK.swn, or use the full path to the file as the argument. IMO, copying the file is not a solution.

Comment: I did change the path.  In fact, the path I used (.../yada yada yada/) was made up to protect the privacy of what I'm working on.  Still no workey (aside from my workaround, which got the job done).  Thanks though; still interested if anyone has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Subprocess expects a list, not a string.  If you only provide a string, it treats the entire thing like an executable name and does not split it on spaces.  It is trying to find a program called "H:/2012/yada yada yada/swanrun" NBK, which would be a file with that title.  Instead try `subprocess.call(['"H:/2012/yada/yada yada/swanrun"', 'NBK'])` which loads the program "H:/2012/yada/yada yada/swanrun" with the argument 'NBK'.